# Calling the same method in all the objects from a class

Tags: python, loops, object, methods

I'm quite new using Python and can't find the answer to this.

Let's souppose I have a code like:

```
class numbers():
   def __init__(self,a,b):
   self._a = a
   self._b = b

   def add(self):
   self._suma = self._a + self._b
```

After that, I create a lot of instances of **numbers**:

```
obj1 = numbers(1,2)
obj2 = numbers(7,16)
...
```

Then, I want to call the **add** method in all the objects of the class **numbers** in a simple and clean way.

Notice that if I instantiated numbers class 1000 times I don't want to write 1000 times this

```
objX.add()
```

---

I looked for an answer in the web and I found that, in other lenguages, they put all the names of the objects in a string, and then iterates on it calling the method.
The problem is I don´t know how to do that in python, nor if it's the best way to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You can have a list of objects called `objs`, where `objs[0]` is the 0th `numbers` object, `objs[1]` is the 1th `numbers` object, etc. Then simply, `for i in range(100): objs[i].add()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a list of objects.

```
   objs = []
```

add elements to this list

```
  obj1 = numbers(1,2) # say these are your objects
  obj2 = numbers(7,16)
  ...
 objs.append(obj1) # add them to the list
```

call the add method for each element in the list

```
 for obj in objs:
     obj.add() # call the add method.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you'll need to have some way to find all the `numbers` objects. For clarity, I'll adjust your code naming conventions slightly so they're more standard (per PEP9).

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def add(self):
        self.sum = self._a + self._b
        return self.sum  # not really sure where we're using it, so here?

a = Number(1, 2)
b = Number(2, 3)
c = Number(3, 4)
```

Now we have three objects, `a`, `b`, and `c`, that are all `Number` objects. There's two ways to get a list of them, and one is really bad. We'll go over that one first.

```
number_objs = [obj for obj in globals() if isinstance(obj, Number)]
for number in number_objs:
    number.add()
```

This queries the all the objects currently in the namespace to see if they're `Number`s. The problem with doing it this way is that you lose encapsulation. You probably don't want to rely on your functions finding a `number` object by calling `globals()`. Instead, let's give `Number` an encompassing object!

```
class NumberList(list):
    # this is literally just a list, but we want to add one method:

    def make_number(a, b):
        number = Number(a, b)
        self.append(number)

all_numbers = NumberList()
a = all_numbers.make_number(1, 2)
b = all_numbers.make_number(2, 3)
c = all_numbers.make_number(3, 4)

for number in all_numbers:
    number.add()
```

Alternatively you can give `Number` a classmethod that works as an alternate constructor, but also adds it to a list. This is probably the cleanest way to handle it.

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def add(self):
        self.sum = self._a + self._b
        return self.sum

    @classmethod
    def track(cls, a, b, container):
        n = cls(a, b)
        container.append(n)
        return n

all_numbers = []
a = Number.track(1, 2, all_numbers)
b = Number.track(2, 3, all_numbers)
c = Number.track(3, 4, all_numbers)

for number in all_numbers:
    number.add()
```

Comment: Good, this is a 'in depth' explanation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to append each obj to a list. To automate that, simply create an empty list and write the code inside the **init**. This will run automatically every time a new object is created

```
class numbers():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        listObjs.append(self)
    
    def Add(self):
        return self.a + self.b

listObjs = []

ob1 = numbers(4,5)
ob2 = numbers(4324,5)
ob3 = numbers(1,25)
ob4 = numbers(2,5324)
ob5 = numbers(21,5)
ob6 = numbers(4213,54)
```

Then simply make a loop and print the obj.Add(). This will run for each obj in the list.

```
for obj in listObjs:
    print(obj.Add())
```

Output:

```
9
4329
26
5326
26
4267
```